# Loading xml data for particular element from xml list with javaScript

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I hope that someone will know how to help me with this problem, I am new to javaScript and XML. Basically I have the xml file with list of products, I have managed to dynamically load the data into an ul li list in my html page, the li elements has title and image, and now I need to be able to click on this li element and load remaining data for a specific product into a new page (or div). I am getting the "Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined" My question is how could I load the correct remaining data after clicking on a specific product from the list of products. (I hope that my explanation is clear enough) here is my code, the first function produces the ul li list in the html page, the displayPRInfo() function should load the data into showPrInfo div for any product which was clicked.

please help me, any help appreciated , thanks for reading.

```
function loadProducts() {
var liOpen=("<li onclick='displayPRInfo(" + i + ")'><p>");
      var divOpen=("</p><div class='prod-sq-img'>");  
      var closingTags=("</div></li>");
    var txt;
    var image;
    var title;


    var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("product");
    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
      { 
      title=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
      image=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("imgfile")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
      txt=  liOpen +  title + divOpen + image + closingTags ;
      document.getElementById("ulList").innerHTML+=txt;
      }

    }
        function displayPRInfo(i)
{
title=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
euPriceRet=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("euror")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
euPriceTrade=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("eurot")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
euPriceSet=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("eset")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
minimumQuantity=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("mqty")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
description=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("desc")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
prBigImg=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("pimgfile")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
prInfo=title+"<br>"+euPriceRet+"<br>"+euPriceTrade+"<br> "+euPriceSet+"<br> "+minimumQuantity+"<br>"+description+"<br>"+ prBigImg ;
document.getElementById("showPrInfo").innerHTML=prInfo;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery to manipulate xml and set onclick events.

```
function loadProducts() {
    var products = $(xmlDoc).find('product');

    for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
      $('#ulList').append('<li id="product_' + i + '"><p>' + $(products[i]).find('title').text() + '</p><div class="prod-sq-img">' + $(products[i]).find('imgfile').text() + '</div></li>');
      $('#product_' + i).click(displayPRInfo.bind($('#product_' + i), products[i]));
    }
 }

function displayPRInfo(xmlProduct) {
  var title= $(xmlProduct).find('title).text();
  var euPriceRet = $(xmlProduct).find('euror').text();
  var euPriceTrade = $(xmlProduct).find('eurot').text();
  var euPriceSet = $(xmlProduct).find('eset').text();
  var minimumQuantity = $(xmlProduct).find('mqty').text();
  var description = $(xmlProduct).find('desc').text();
  var prBigImg = $(xmlProduct).find('pimgfile').text();
  var prInfo = title+"<br>"+euPriceRet+"<br>"+euPriceTrade+"<br> "+euPriceSet+"<br> "+minimumQuantity+"<br>"+description+"<br>"+ prBigImg ;
  $('#showPrInfo').html(prInfo);
}
```

Comment: Hmm, how to provide the next, previous item option within this code? I have been trying to bite this since the morning and nothing worked for me so far, basically the user should be able to navigate between the products using next, prev buttons and the displayPRInfo() should each time display info for that item. How should I start?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried the whole script but for sure you have to move this:

```
liOpen=("<li onclick='displayPRInfo(" + i + ")'><p>")
```

into the for loop

```
for (i=0; i<x.length; i++) { 
    title=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    image=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("imgfile")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    liOpen=("<li onclick='displayPRInfo(" + i + ")'><p>");
    txt=  liOpen +  title + divOpen + image + closingTags ;
    document.getElementById("ulList").innerHTML+=txt;
}
```

where acctually `i` is defined

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, it kinda sorted the "Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined" but now I am getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined " any ideas? thank you

Comment: @Kugarek One that doesn't change a lot of code is making x global or getting x again in displayPRInfo `function displayPRInfo(i)
{ var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("product"); ...`

Comment: Thank for the reply, I sure that your answer would help, I have also tried the answer from George Acev and it also works perfectly, thank you for answering my questions.

Answer (score 0):

I found this and it helped me a bit, the thing is that I want to load images by request, not loading them all at once but by clicking a button and set the img src with the xml data, I have this...

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <style>
        #iosslider_nav {
            height: 13px;
            right: 10px;
            /* align right side */
            /*left: 10px;*/
            /* align left side */

            bottom: 10px;
            /*position: absolute;*/
            /* set if needed */
            /*margin-top: 10px;*/
            /* remove if position is absolute */
        }

        #iosslider_nav .btn {
            width: 13px;
            height: 13px;
            background: #eaeaea;
            margin: 0 5px 0 0;
            -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
            -moz-border-radius: 100%;
            border-radius: 100%;
            cursor: pointer;
            float: left;
            /* ie 7/8 fix */

            background: url('../images/bull_off.png') no-repeat\9;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="ninja_slider"></div>
    <div id="iosslider_nav"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc("xml/xml_data.xml");

        // generic load xml data function
        function loadXMLDoc(filename) {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else { // code for IE5 and IE6
                xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xhttp.open("GET", filename, false);
            xhttp.send();
            return xhttp.responseXML;
        }

        set_slider();
        //set_navigation('xml/xml_data.xml', 'iosslider_nav');

        function set_slider() {
            var item_div = $(xmlDoc).find('desk');
            var item_btn = $(xmlDoc).find('desk');
            var item_img = $(xmlDoc).find('desk');

            // Object.bind() handler for ie 7/8
            if (!Function.prototype.bind) {
                Function.prototype.bind = function (oThis) {
                    if (typeof this !== 'function') {
                        // closest thing possible to the ECMAScript 5
                        // internal IsCallable function
                        throw new TypeError('Function.prototype.bind - what is trying to be bound is not callable');
                    }
                    var aArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1),
                        fToBind = this,
                        fNOP = function () {},
                        fBound = function () {
                            return fToBind.apply(this instanceof fNOP && oThis ? this : oThis,
                                aArgs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
                        };
                    fNOP.prototype = this.prototype;
                    fBound.prototype = new fNOP();
                    return fBound;
                };
            }

            // create main div's
            for (var i = 0; i < item_div.length; i++) {
                $('#ninja_slider').append('<div id="item_div' + i + '"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="item_anchor"><img id="item_img' + i + '" src="" class="ninja_item"></a></div>');
                $('#item_div' + i).on('click', load_current.bind($('#item_div' + i), item_div[i]));
            }

            // load first element
            $('#ninja_slider #item_div0 .item_anchor img').attr('src', $(item_img[0]).find('image').text());


            // create nav div's
            for (var i = 0; i < item_btn.length; i++) {
                $('#iosslider_nav').append('<div id="item_btn' + i + '" class="btn"></div>');
                $('#item_btn' + i).on('click', load_current.bind($('#item_btn' + i), item_btn[i]));
            }
        }

        function load_current(xmlData) {
            var image = $(xmlData).find('image').text();
            var src = image;
            //console.log(image);
            var item_img = $(xmlDoc).find('desk');
            for (var i = 0; i < item_img.length; i++) {
                $('#ninja_slider').append('<div id="item_div' + i + '"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="item_anchor"><img id="item_img' + i + '" src="' + $(item_img[i]).find('image').text() + '" class="ninja_item"></a></div>');
            }
        }

        function set_navigation(url, id) {
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                async: false,
                type: "GET",
                data: "xml",
                success: function (xml) {
                    $(xml).find("desk").each(function () {
                        var item_nav = document.getElementById(id),
                            click_item = document.createElement("div");

                        item_nav.appendChild(click_item);
                        click_item.className = click_item.className + "btn";
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

hope it makes sense...